# Limit NSRegularExpression by object

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

Currently I'm using NSRegularExpression to extract Images from a rss output. This is what I use:

```
for (NSDictionary *story in stories) {

    NSString *string = [story objectForKey:@"content:encoded"];

    NSRange rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);

    NSString *pattern = @"<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>";
    NSError* error = nil;

    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *matchs = [regex matchesInString:[story objectForKey:@"content:encoded"] options:0 range:rangeOfString];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matchs) {
        NSLog(@"url: %@", [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
    }


}
```

And this work really fine, except that I only need one image link per Key in Stories, even if it is the case (like this one) that are more than one image per key.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you need to do here is replace your "`matches`" loop:

```
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matchs) {
    NSLog(@"url: %@", [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
}
```

with this:

```
if([matchs count] > 0)
{
    [storyMatches addObject: [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]];
}
```

Making sure to declare that storyMatches mutable array before you start looping through `stories`:

```
NSMutableArray *storyMatches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In other words, your code should look something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *storyMatches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[stories count]];

for (NSDictionary *story in stories) {

    NSString *string = [story objectForKey:@"content:encoded"];

    NSRange rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);

    NSString *pattern = @"<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>";
    NSError* error = nil;

    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *matchs = [regex matchesInString:[story objectForKey:@"content:encoded"] options:0 range:rangeOfString];
    if([matchs count] > 0)
    {
        [storyMatches addObject:[string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"storyMatches count is %d and contents is %@", [storyMatches count], [storyMatches description]);
```

Comment: its giving me this error `"No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'rangeAtIndex:' "`

Comment: match is not a NSArray object but instead a "`NSTextCheckingResult`", right?

Comment: Michael my bad, I wasn't replacing the code in the right way.

Its still printing 17 objects instead of 10.

Comment: are there 10 "stories" or 17 "stories"?

Comment: so even using my code, you have 10 stories but 17 matches appearing?